# Regular Expression problem with angular brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

(Sorry, I could not think of a good title.)

What is the regular expression, preferably in JavaScript Regex or the one that is used in the Python `re` package, for:

> Find everything that is not a letter (with and without diacritics), a number, whitespace, `<` nor `>` and is not between a `<` and a `>`

So for example, after searching:

`The qui,ck <brow'n> f0x.`

It returns:

`,` and `.`

Thank you!

Comment: Using pure regex for this seems tortured. Make a copy of the string if necessary, remove anything between `<` and `>`, then search for the character class you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `[^a-zA-Z]` - not a letter,
- `[^\d]` - not a number (a single digit to be precise),
- `[^\s]` - not a whitespace,
- `[^<>]` - not a `<` or `>`.
- `(?![^<]*>)` - is not between `<` and `>`.

```js
const str = "The qui,ck <brow'n> f0x."

const res = str.match(/([^a-zA-Z\s\d<>])(?![^<]*>)/g)
console.log(res)
```